# How to drop a buffer of rows in a data frame around rows of a certain condition

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I am trying to remove rows in a data frame that are within x rows after rows meeting a certain condition.

I have a data frame with a response variable, a measurement type that represents the condition, and time. Here's a mock data set:

```
data <- data.frame(rlnorm(45,0,1),
        c(rep(1,15),rep(2,15),rep(1,15)),
        seq(
            from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:00", tz="EST"),
            to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:44", tz="EST"),
            by="min"))
names(data) <- c('Variable','Type','Time')
```

In this mock case, I want to delete the first 5 rows in condition 1 after condition 2 occurs.

The way I thought about solving this problem was to generate a separate vector that determines the distance that each observation that is a 1 is from the last 2. Here's the code I wrote:

```
dist = vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {

    if(data$Type[i] != 1) dist[i] <- 0

    else {
      position = i
      tempcount = 0
      while(position > 0 && data$Type[position] == 1){
          position = position - 1
          tempcount = tempcount + 1
      }
      dist[i] = tempcount
    }
}
```

This code will do the trick, but it's extremely inefficient. I was wondering if anyone had some cleverer, faster solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the trick:

```
criteria1 = which(data$Type[2:nrow(data)] == 2 & data$Type[2:nrow(data)] != data$Type[1:nrow(data)-1]) +1
criteria2 = as.vector(sapply(criteria1,function(x) seq(x,x+5)))
data[-criteria2,]
```

How it works:

1. criteria1 contains indices where Type==2, but the previous row is not the same type. The strange lookign subsets like 2:nrow(data) are because we want to compare to the previous row, but for the first row there is no previous row. herefore we add +1 at then end.
2. criteria2 contains sequences starting with the number in criteria1, to those numbers+5
3. the third row performs the subset

This might need small modification, I wasn't exactly clear what criteria 1 and criteria 2 were from your code. Let me know if this works or you need any more advice!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. If you could accept my answer by clicking the checkmark that would be great ;)

Comment: @user2130093 Your're question is unclear. Your title basically states "drop rows _around_ rows of condition". In the text, you write "want to delete rows _after_ the condition (Type = 2?)". This answer removes rows _before_ Type = 2. Please clarify - make your example smaller and show the expected output (e.g. remove redundant variables and reduce number of rows).